# How to load a User Control dynamically from a dll into asp:panel

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I have more than 3 websites. So I want to share some common user controls among these applications. For this purpose i have created a new web application having common user controls i.e login, and some other controls. Then i produce the ddl which i load into my other web sites using below code:

But i unable to load the user control from dll into panel using below code as we do by `using Control c = Page.LoadContnrol("contrlname.ascx")`.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(pluginPath);
Type controlType = assembly.GetType("ABCCommon.controls.LoginPanel");
object controlss = Activator.CreateInstance(controlType);      

// this section doesn't load the user control from dll into panel

pnlLoginControl.Controls.Add((Control)c);
```

or

```
Assembly plugin = Assembly.LoadFrom(pluginPath);

    Type[] types = plugin.GetTypes();

    foreach (Type t in types)
    {
        if (typeof(UserControl).IsAssignableFrom(t))
        {
            UserControl control = (UserControl)Activator.CreateInstance(t);

            controls.Add(control);
        }
    }

    UserControl c = (UserControl)controls[0];
```

// this section doesn't load the user control from dll into panel

```
    this.pnlLoginControl.Controls.Add(c);
```

Please can anyone help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the VirtualPathProvider to do this. The problem is that Controls.Add(c) expects to find the ascx file but that's in another project.

This [tutorial](http://www.cmswire.com/cms/tips-tricks/aspnet-reusing-web-user-controls-and-forms-000915.php) explains the step to take.

Comment: Thanks Wouter de Kort, yeah this is a helpful article.

Answer (score 0):

A user control is not specified in an assembly. The user control is defined by the .ascx file and gets compiled by asp.net on runtime in a temporary assembly.

To instantiate user controls you should use the method [`Page.LoadControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcontrol.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, You mean Page.LoadContnrol("contrlname.ascx"), but i want to load from dll?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a reference to the DLL in your project, and use the overloaded `LoadControl` method that accepts a type (and any parameters passed to the constructor):

```
MyControl ctrl = LoadControl(typeof(MyControl), null);
```

The second argument is for passing arguments into a parameterized constructor.

**EDIT**

If these are custom server controls, just add a refernce to the DLL in your project and import the assembly on whatever pages are using the control:

```
using ABCCommon.Controls;
```

Use the control:

```
LoginPanel loginPanel = new LoginPanel();
loginPanel.ID = "loginPanel1";
pnlLoginControl.Controls.Add(loginPanel);
```

Comment: thx James, i have used this technique also, but it didn't work for me!

Comment: How didn't it work? What happened? It didn't show or didn't compile?

Comment: No its a user control, and i have included the reference as well, And returns the control to the object here: `ChilliCommon.controls.LoginPanel abc = (ChilliCommon.controls.LoginPanel)LoadControl(typeof(ChilliCommon.controls.LoginPanel), null); ` but returns null buttons and textboxes on the login user control

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not registering the assembly in the web.config and declaring the control in markup?

Comment: I didn't understand your point could you please elaborate it: "and declaring the control in markup"?